# In the new scrum tfs2010 what is the relation between SBT and Sprint

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I am trying to understand the new scrum template of tfs2010.  I understand that PBIs are implemented by SBTs.  but how is an SBT linked to a sprint. I mean, how do I specify that this SBT belongs to this sprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a Product Backlog Item work item type.

You associate the two by setting the Iteration Path of the Sprint work item, then setting the same iteration path on the PBI (or any other work item).

Comment: yes, but but we can create sprints...which we plan to deliver..with start dates and end dates and capacity.  And sbts should belong to this sprint. but i see no space in the process to this this.

Comment: "sbts" (what is an "sbt"?) are associated with a sprint through the iteration path. That's how it works. For the burndown chart, etc., the sprint start and end dates are used to find the sprint; that determines the iteration path of the current sprint; then all the tasks for the same iteration are located.

Comment: I didnet see that a sprint title can only be one of the iterations. :)
In previous template, we could give any name to sprint, so i was confused . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [Aaron Bjork's session on \BUILD](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-793T) on this subject to understand this better.

I believe he is using the Agile process template, but the same principles can be applied to the scrum template.